# Unit test not behaving for a class that extends a base class

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am struggling with a test for a component class which extends another abstract class.

The two classes are as follows:

```
export abstract class BaseListComponent {
    constructor(
        protected someImportantService: SomeImportantService
    ){

    }

    handleListInitialization() {
        // Do lots of things
        this.doOtherStuff();
    }

    /**
     * @abstract doOtherStuff Function
     */
    protected abstract doOtherStuff( );
}


export class MyListComponent extends BaseListComponent {
    constructor(
        someImportantService: SomeImportantService,
        private listService: ListService
    ) {
        super( someImportantService );
    }

    doStuff = () => {
        this.handleListInitialization();
    }

    doOtherStuff(){
        this.listService.getThings().then(() => {
            // process response...
         })
    }
}
```

I'm trying to test that when calling `doStuff` in `MyListComponent` it will result in calling `listService.getThings()` in the `doOtherStuff` method.

```
describe('When calling doStuff()', () => {
        it('should call getThings from the ListService instance', (  ) => {
            spyOn(component.listService, 'getThings').and.returnValue(Promise.then({foo: 'bar'}));
            component.doStuff();
            expect(component.listService.getThings).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });
```

When executing this test I get an error saying the spy was never called, but oddly my coverage report shows the lines of my `doOtherStuff()` implementation fully covered.

If I call `doOtherStuff()` instead in my test suite, then the test passes just fine.

I'm don't understand why this is happening, I am wondering if my abstract base class has been implemented incorrectly somehow, although when running the application things are working as I would expect.

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is when `doOtherStuff` is called, just in that moment you are subscribing/attending the Promise.

If you want to receive the value of `this.listService.getThings()` you will need yo wait until the next clock will be executed.

To handle this you can use [fakeAysnc](https://angular.io/guide/testing#async-test-with-fakeasync) and [tick](https://angular.io/guide/testing#the-tick-function) of Angular.

I think we can rewrite your test with fakeAsync like this:

```
describe('When calling doStuff()',() => {
        it('should call getThings from the ListService instance',  fakeAsync(() => {
            component.doStuff();
            tick();
            fixture.detectChanges();
            spyOn(component.listService, 'getThings').and.returnValue(Promise.then({foo: 'bar'}));
            tick();
            fixture.detectChanges();
            expect(component.listService.getThings).toHaveBeenCalled();
        }));
});
```

It should work with that.

Answer (score 0):

you need to post more code how you create the `component`, maybe it's mocked, in this case the failure is expected. The classes and their inheritance look good and should pass the test in described circumstances.